# civix unknown extension after creating a new extension

Tags: civicrm, civicrm-extension

I have created a new extension on civicrm using civix on the CLI. It installs successfully and then asks if I would like to enable it. When I say yes I get the Install error: unknown extension. Please assist
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqLfx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it turns out that I just had to point the CLI to "C:\xampp\htdocs\civicrm\sites\default\files\civicrm\ext"
which is where all extensions should be installed

Comment: I got same error, and found your answer helpful. but my extension is not yet listed in the extension list. what should be the very next step? Socondly, don't know how you find your solution, but this path is not mentioned in the online documentation. where did you go then?

Comment: @Alvaro Masitsa: When you say "I just had to point the CLI to C:\xampp\htdocs\civicrm\sites\default\files\civicrm\ext", you mean that the `civix` command must be executed in the directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\civicrm\sites\default\files\civicrm\ext", for the record.